# JQuery on() method in native javascript for dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for native JavaScript code for this example with jQuery:

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".child", function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

What I did so far works with the elements that come with the page but not the dynamically generated ones:

```
var children = document.getElementById("parent").getElementsByClassName("child");
for (var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++)
{
    children[i].onclick = foo;
}
function foo(el)
{
    alert("child clicked");
}
```

How can I make this code work for the dynamically generated elements?

If you are looking for the answer, here it is:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/2748984

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/6746555

Comment: make sure you set the `children` variable *after* you generate the dynamic content.  Otherwise it will be `null`.

Comment: @Mahi thanks i closed the question as duplicate

Comment: idk why someone downvote a question i closed it myself -_-

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like the following, which listens for elements being added to the document, and then binds your function. I would also recommend binding an event listener rather than assigning your method to the `onclick` attribute, but check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) to see what you really need:

```
    // listen for new elements being added to the document
    document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
        // check if they're the type of node you're looking for
        if (event.relatedNode.querySelectorAll('your selector')) {
            // bind the event listener
            event.relatedNode.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                // your code
            });
        }
    });
```